# Push amended/rebase commits that were already commited

Tags: git, rebase

Just to be sure ...

I'm working INDIVIDUALLY on a branch that was already pushed in ou git repo.

Is it safe to push amended/rebases commits from that branch if I'm absolutely sure no one else is working on that branch ?

Answer (score 0):

I use rebases in my private cloned repo branches, when i am sure that there is only two copies of this branch and all of them under my control — origin and local.

If you work with personal branch in public repo, be extremely careful that no one else is working on it.

It is okay if you'll make rebase right before pull request or merge to upstream and branch deletion.